# get NSURLSession download progress in all view controllers

Tags: nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

So i have a FirstViewController where i download a video with the progress view and progress is working fine using this code

```
func startDownloading() {
    let download = Downloads(url: videoUrl!.absoluteString!)
    download.downloadTask = self.downloadsSession.downloadTaskWithURL(videoUrl!)                    
    download.downloadTask!.resume()
    download.isDownloading = true

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    // 1
    print("URLSession Completed for url \(downloadTask.originalRequest?.URL?.absoluteString)")

    if let originalURL = downloadTask.originalRequest?.URL?.absoluteString,
        destinationURL = localFilePathForUrl(originalURL) {

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtURL(destinationURL)
        } catch {
            // Non-fatal: file probably doesn't exist
        }
        do {
            try! fileManager.copyItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not copy file to disk: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    print("URLSession inProgress \(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))")


    if let downloadUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest?.URL?.absoluteString,
        let download = activeDownloads[downloadUrl] {
        //THIS SETS THE PROGRESS
        download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)


        self.downloadView.state = .Downloading
            self.downloadView.setProgress(Double(totalSize)!, animated: true)    

    }  
}
```

now this code updates FirstViewControllers *downloadView.progress* correctly but what i want is when i go to *SecondViewController* i should get the progress of this ongoing download in SecondVC too without starting the download progress again (i know downloading again would be very dumb).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to separate your network request manager code from the view controller:

- Create a separate class to manage the requests, and move your delegate code there.
- In the `didWriteData` method, use `NSNotificationCenter` to broadcast the notification to any interested view class or make your first view controller notify the second one if it exists.
- In each of your view controller classes, register for the notification and when you receive it, update the status accordingly.

Comment: i was thinking about the same thing but couldn't find anyone using it, do you think it is it best possible way?